# Visual Studio - WPF - References not adding properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have looked through past questions on this issue to no avail.

I've just created a new WPF project in VS 2013. I go to Add Reference, and select System.Windows.Form. It adds. Great!

However, the appropriate tools are still greyed out in the toolbox. Yes, auto-update toolbox is on. I've shown all. I've restarted VS and rebuilt my solution. I've added `using System.Windows.Forms;` to my MainWindow.xaml.cs file.

At this, I only have the bare bones code because this is a completely new project that I haven't touched yet.

What am I missing?? I've tried dragging the .dll file to the toolbox, tools are still greyed. Is there a piece of code I'm missing somewhere?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace sub20tool3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
<Window x:Class="sub20tool3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You cannot Directly host Winforms controls in WPF. You need to use WindowsFormHost to add Winforms control in wpf. Refer Simple tutorial http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/

Comment: Additionally, if you are just looking for standard controls to put on the WPF page, use the WPF versions of those controls, not the WinForms versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a WindowsFormHost element to hold winforms controls in a WPF project. The WindowsFormHost also needs a reference to WindowsFormIntegration.

Here's a good tutorial on how to use them: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Misc_controls.WindowsFormsHostSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        Title="WindowsFormsHostSample" Height="350" Width="450">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="wfhSample">
            <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                <wf:WebBrowser DocumentTitleChanged="wbWinForms_DocumentTitleChanged" />
            </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```